# Get email address of customer with Quickbooks PHP SDK

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am working with Quickbooks and need to access the customer email address. But I get a value like below from `$Customer->getPrimaryEmailAddr()`

```
 QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryEmailAddr Object
(
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [Address] => Array
            (
                [0] => Surf@Intuit.com  
            )

    )

)
```

How can I get the email address?

Comment: Please post your actual code. You are getting answers which don't work for you because you didn't post your code, so no one has any idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *the specific object you posted in your question* you want to do this:

`$address = $TheObject->getAddress();`

However, based on your comments to other users, I suspect you're using this code within a loop (e.g. looping through a list of customers), which means that you'll want an additional check to make sure the customer actually has a primary email address at all (otherwise you'll end up seeing errors like `Call to a member function getAddress() on null`):

```
foreach ($customers as $Customer)
{
  if ($PrimaryEmailAddr = $Customer->getPrimaryEmailAddr())
  {
    $address = $PrimaryEmailAddr->getPrimaryEmailAddr();
  }
}
```

Another way to handle this is to use the XPath method, so that you don't need the extra check:

```
foreach ($customers as $Customer)
{
    print('  Email: ' . $Customer->getXPath('//Customer/PrimaryEmailAddr/Address') . "\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get address with:

```
$address = $Customer->getPrimaryEmailAddr()->getAddress();
```

Comment: it's return `Call to a member function getAddress() on null`

Comment: Can you check your code? If `$Customer->getPrimaryEmailAddr()` returns  `QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryEmailAddr` it is not `null`.

Comment: I have checked but it returns `getAddress() on null` only

Comment: @Balachandiran  Post your full code. My bet would be that this answer is correct, but that you didn't post enough of your code for the poster to anticipate that you're looping through many customers, some of which may not even have a PrimaryEmailAddr object at all.